# using fwrite as an atomic process on Linux

Tags: c, linux, atomic, fwrite

I am developing a C code on Linux environment. I use `fwrite` to write some data to some files. The program will be run on an environment that power cut offs occur often (at least once a day). Therefore, I want `fwrite` to ensure that the file should not be updated if a power cut occurs while it is writing data. It should only save the file when the `fwrite` finishes its job. How can I use `fwrite` that effects the file only it finishes the writing process?

EDIT: I use fopen with `wb` to discard the previous info in the file and write a new file e.g.

```
FILE *rtng_p;
rtng_p = fopen("/etc/routing_table", "wb");
fwrite(&user_list, sizeof(struct routing), 40, rtng_p);
```

and it is a very small data some bytes long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First write the file to a temporary path on the same filesystem, like `/etc/routing_table.tmp`. Then just rename the copy on top of original file. Renames are guaranteed atomic.

So, the sequence of calls would be, `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, `rename`.

Comment: Just to give a reference to anyone wondering if the claim that renames are guaranteed to be atomic is accurate: [See the wikipedia article on renames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rename_(computing)#Atomic_rename). Take note that this is valid for all POSIX applications.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the sequence given in [David Schwartz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17304744/841108) you could perhaps use advisory locks with e.g. [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) syscall (or maybe [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) i.e. [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) with `F_SETLK` ....)

That would mean to add, just after

```
 FILE * fil = fopen("/etc/routing_table.tmp", "wb");
```

the lines

```
 if (!fil) 
   { perror("/etc/routing_table.tmp"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 if (flock(fileno(fil), LOCK_EX)) 
   { perror("flock LOCK_EX"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and at the end, you would

```
 if (fflush(fil)) /* flush the file before unlocking it!!*/
   { perror("fflush"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 if (flock(fileno(fil), LOCK_UN))
   { perror("flock LOCK_UN"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 if (fclose (fil))
   { perror("fclose"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };;
 if (rename("/etc/routing_table.tmp", "/etc/routing_table"))
   { perror("rename"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Using such advisory locking would ensure that even if two processes of your program are running, only one would write the file.

But it is overkill probably.

BTW, you seems to write binary data in `/etc/`. I believe it is against the habits or the conventions (see [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html), or [Linux Standard Base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb)). I expect files under `/etc` to be textual. Perhaps you want your file under `/var/lib` ?

See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book online.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a large argument going on in the UNIX/Linux community about the whether the `open/write/close/rename` pattern (as described in [David Schwartz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17304744/215266)) is actually guaranteed to be atomic. Note this conversation is about `write` and not `fwrite`!

The primary author of the EXT4 filesystem did not believe that it should be guaranteed according to POSIX and early versions of the filesystem did not treat it as atomic. Eventually he capitulated and made that set of operations atomic as the default behavior for EXT4. The claim was made, however, that user programs should actually be doing `open/write/fsync/close/rename`.

Other filesystems may not guarantee atomicity without the `fsync`, and if EXT4 is mounted with `noauto_da_alloc` then that guarantee is lost there as well. So if you want to be really safe you should add `fsync` after `close` before the `rename`. I haven't tried this with `fwrite` it might work if you use `fflush`.

See the `auto_da_alloc` section at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt for more information. Also see an article written by the primary author of EXT4 here: http://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/03/12/delayed-allocation-and-the-zero-length-file-problem/

Comment: Barring a crash, `open/write/close/rename` is _logically_ atomic [because `rename` is], which is what OP [and most] are concerned with. To provide atomicity across a crash, it should be `open/write/fsync/close/rename/fsync` where the 2nd `fsync` is for the file descriptor of the containing _directory_ [otherwise, it is not updated immediately]. Otherwise, after a crash, you'll have updated file data but the directory may point to the old inode [the ondisk copy of the dirent was never updated]. BTW, if you `close` before `fsync`, you have no fd for the `fsync`